# No error displayed in console, simple counting program won't work

Tags: java

So, I am learning Java coming from Python and Scheme, and when I tried to run this simple piece of code it won't give me any type of error log, or anything at all. I don't fully understand about classes and such, so this may be the problem.

Can someone explain what's is happening, why, and how to fix it?

```
class midnight {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int hour, minute, seconds, tomidnight, total;
        hour = 1;   
        minute = 45;
        seconds = 42;
        total = 86400;
        tomidnight = (((hour*3600)+(minute*60)+seconds) - total);
        System.out.println(tomidnight);

    }
}
```

Comment: it show me `-80058` what is your IDE? how you run this code?

Comment: Are you looking at the right output console? Or are you running it properly?

Comment: I used Eclipse. I see what's happening, should be total minus the amount of seconds elapsed since midnight. But anyway, still doesn't run on my Eclipse. Tried running on some online compiler, and gives me the same results.

Comment: If you don't tell how you run the code, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead, we can't really help other than giving you a link to the eclipse documentation explaining how to run Java code.

Comment: To fix what? you have no any errors with your code. Do it by your hands then you will get the same result. If result doesn't match your need, then try to write a correct method>

Comment: Can you try running it from the command line? `javac midnight.java` followed by `java midnight` (You will have to be in the same directory as the file `midnight.java` for these commands to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some additional info in the printout, for example:

```
System.out.println("Tomidnight: " + tomidnight);
```

If you run the class from the terminal you must first compile with the following command:

```
javac midnight.java
```

And to execute the class, use the following command:

```
java midnight
```

This is the output: `Tomidnight: -80058`

Answer (score 1):

It shows `-80058` in cmd because if you do this calculation in calculator then also you will get this number only. It just because of calculation and nothing else.